# How to pass a variable from my controller, to the HTML, then to a JS function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

My controller ultimately renders this:

```
res.render('my-html', { title: `${title}`, myVar1, myVar2 });
```

In the HTML, I can access the variables in order to display data directly into the HTML. But what I'm trying to do is then pass those variables into a client-side JS function:

```
function myClientSideFunction(myVar1) {
   console.log(myVar1)
};
```

My webpack entry point file says:

'Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar1 is not defined'

I'm using Pug/Jade if that info helps.

Comment: Have you defined these `myVar1, myVar2` before using them `{ title: '${title}', myVar1, myVar2 }` here?

Comment: Yes, they're queries from mongodb that are returning values. I can display them in the html just can't pass them to the js function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a Node.js variable to the inside of a Pug script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574113/how-to-pass-a-node-js-variable-to-the-inside-of-a-pug-script-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define those variables on the rendered HTML page in a `script` tag via Pug:

```
script.
  var myVar1 = #{myVar1};
```

Then you could access them like any other javascript variable client-side.

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions that have already been answered, flag them as duplicates.

Comment: @Graham Had searched for a duplicate but didn't find one. Thanks for adding it.