# How to pass object from Express app to Pug frontend?

Tags: express, pug

So I am having issues passing data from my express backend to my pug front end. I am wanting to render the locations data pull from my db, pass it through to the locations page and iterate over the locations data. The data is not getting recognized by the browser. What am I doing wrong?

app.js

```
    app.get('/:store_id', async (req, res) => {
      await db.stores.findById(req.params.store_id)
        .then(locations => {

          // example of locations
          locations = [ 
          {
            location: 'Fremont',
            latitude: 37.49267,
            longitude: -121.94409
          },
          {
            location: 'Folsom',
            latitude: 38.64392,
            longitude: -121.18621
          }
        ];
        res.render('location', {locations})
      }).catch(error => res.render('landing'))
    })
```

location.pug

```
block content
    script.

        locations.forEach(function(sc) {
          // do something with sc
        }
```

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"pug": "^2.0.4",
```

Comment: I know there are some variations for accepting pug variables - like #{variable} & !{variable} but not quite sure of the difference or use case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a Node.js variable to the inside of a Pug script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574113/how-to-pass-a-node-js-variable-to-the-inside-of-a-pug-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

That's going to render as a script block in the processed HTML file:

```
<script>
  locations.forEach(function(sc) {
      // ...
  }
</script>
```

It likely won't do anything on page load (unless you happen to have an iterable `locations` variable available). You want to use Pug's [iteration syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html):

```
content
  each location in location
    //- do stuff
```