# How to use a JavaScript variable's in a "each" iteration on Pug (Jade)

Tags: javascript, pug

(If the following question has English errors, tell me and I'll correct them.)

Hey, I have to do a project using Pug, I've done everything but now I'm stuck because I have to get a variable from the pug render to use it and show only 1 row when I click on the change button of my list.

At the start of my code, there's a script part with a function `getValue`,

```
  script(src='book_list.js')
  script  
    | function getValue(value){
    |  const hello = document.getElementById("test")
    |  $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show')
    |  hello.innerHTML = value
    |  window.test = value
    |  console.log(hello)
    |  alert(window.test)
    |  console.log(hello.innerHTML)
    | }
```

When I use the function, the `hello.innerHTML` is printed on the console, but when I use the same `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML`, it makes an error.

```
each book in message
  - var testISBN = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    if  !{testISBN} != book.isbn
      each val in book 
        p
        hr
        hr
        img(src="", alt="")
        label.col-form-label(for='recipient-name') #{val}
        input#recipient-name.form-control(type='text' value=`${val}`)
```

And the result is :

```
    58|                 .form-group

    59|                   each book in message

  > 60|                     - var testISBN = document.getElementById("test") .innerHTML;

    61|                     if  !{testISBN} != book.isbn

    62|                       each val in book 

    63|                         p


Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined
```

Also can someone tell me if I used the unescaped string interpolation correctly in the line below ? Thanks for your help

Comment: You have a `locals` variable within the route for this pug page which contains variables such as your `message`. This route is a .js file that contains code executed for the page to be rendered. You then have front-end javascript. I think you are getting the two mixed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a Node.js variable to the inside of a Pug script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574113/how-to-pass-a-node-js-variable-to-the-inside-of-a-pug-script-tag)

Comment: No it didn't. I edited the original post.

Comment: The first part of your question asks about a JavaScript error in the browser, but the second part asks about a pug rendering error on the server.  Please only ask about one issue per question on StackOverflow.